# OGNL invoke an enum's static property's method

Tags: static, struts2, ognl

I have an enum like this:

```java
package languages;

public enum Language
{
  ENG, GER, FRA;

  public static final Language DEFAULT = ENG;
}
```

I'd like to get the name of the `DEFAULT` static variable in `JSP` using `OGNL` by invoking the `name()` method on it.

I tried these but none of them worked:

1. `<s:property value="%{@languages.Language@DEFAULT.name()}" />`
2. `<s:property value="@languages.Language@DEFAULT.name()" />`
3. `<s:property value="@languages.Language@DEFAULT@name()" />`

but this worked:
`<s:property value="@languages.Language@ENG.name()" />`

Comment: Fixed in OGNL `3.1.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. At least not w/o some workaround.

When it comes to accessing static fields in enum - OGNL will call static `valueOf` method of `java.lang.Enum` class.

With your expression it will be something like that:

```
Enum.valueOf(Language.class, "DEFAULT");
```

Which results in `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` being thrown because the specified enum type has no constant with the specified name.

Answer (score 1):

It is relatively easy to fix the ognl library as described here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4479

Hopefully it will make it into a future struts2 release.