# struts 2 - How to access static EnumSet from jsp

Tags: struts2

I have an Enum like below:

```
public enum ElectionEventStatus {
NEW("enum.electioneventstatus.new"), 
POLLING_NOMINATIONS("enum.electioneventstatus.pollingnominations"), 
POLLED_NOMINATIONS("enum.electioneventstatus.pollednominations"),
POLLING_VOTES("enum.electioneventstatus.pollingvotes"),
POLLED_VOTES("enum.electioneventstatus.polledvotes"),
COMPLETED("enum.electioneventstatus.completed"),
INVALIDATED("enum.electioneventstatus.invalidated"),
;

public static final EnumSet<ElectionEventStatus> closedStatuses = EnumSet.of(POLLED_VOTES, COMPLETED);

private final String messageKey;

private ElectionEventStatus(String messageKey) {
    this.messageKey = messageKey;
}

public String getMessageKey() {
    return messageKey;
}
}
```

How can I refer to the closedStatus Enumset in jsp? I have enabled static access in struts.xml

```
<constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true"/>
```

and tried to access the EnumSet like this but it did not work(I have verified the package name was correct). Thanks.

```
<s:if test="%{electionEventStatus in @net.tangs.business.electionevent.constants.ElectionEventStatus@closedStatuses}">
```

Comment: or maybe this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26535473/1700321.

Comment: It is your second link which explained this. Thanks.